# Filtrate Report's Content based on Account

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

Goal:
Filtrate the report's content in SSRS based on user's account or similiar.

When the user enter on (instance).com/reports and click on a report, the content should be filtrated based on the user's logging account in the report. User shall read his/her data, not others in the report.

Problem:
Is it possible to do it?

Information:
*Data source is SSAS.
*using MDX coding in the report
*I'm using SQl server 2008R2 standard edition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty simple stuff to do in SSRS.
First step to do this - you need to have dimension in SSAS with users list.
Then - pass strtomember parameters to MDX query from build-in fields UserId,
Off course your user dimm need to be sliced with associated dimensions , or you can manually create sets/groups depend of execution user.